# Не работают миграции с DB

Tags: php, laravel, php7

Не работает миграция в laravel с СУБД
Попытки найти самостоятельно причину не увенчались успехом , жду помощи или подсказок от всех желающих...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гуглите PDOException("could not find driver")

Comment: какой версии PHP? какой драйвер используете? Если я правильно понял используете PHP7 + PDO MySQL, посмотрите раскомментирована ли у вас строка в PHP.ini extension=pdo_mysql.dll(Вроде так пишется)